# Can Testing A Decision Tree Lead To No Prediction?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, cart

I am training an ID3 (classification) and regression tree. When testing against my testing set, I come across instances where there are no branches that meet the criteria in my training set. This leads to an inability of my tree to make a prediction. Is there something I am not accounting for in my code to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Can you see the tree, the questions being asked, and what happens with one of your failed examples? Are there missing values? Are the questions $x >c$ or $x<c$ with $x=c$ breaking the system?